# Не получается отправлять личные сообщения в чате

Tags: c#, tcp

Сделал TCP чат(клиент/сервер), есть ip юзеров онлайн, готов глобальный чат.
Проблема возникла на создании личных сообщений. Юзер должен в комбо боксе выбрать ip и написать сообщение лично.

Глобальный чат:

```
private void Chatting()
    {
        try
        {
            IPEndPoint ipPoint = new
                IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(Address), Port);

            socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            socket.Connect(ipPoint);
            while (true)
            {
                byte[] data = new byte[256];
                string builder = string.Empty;
                int bytes = socket.Receive(data, data.Length, 0);
                builder += Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
                if (builder != string.Empty)
                {
                    if (builder.StartsWith("RemoteEndPoint"))
                    {
                        ActiveUsers.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                        {
                            if(!ActiveUsers.Items.Contains(ActiveUsers.Items.Add(builder.Remove(0, 14))))
                                ActiveUsers.Items.Add(builder.Remove(0, 14));
                            ActiveUsers_SelectionChanged(null, null);
                        }));
                        continue;
                    }
                    GlobalChat.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { GlobalChat.Text += builder + "\n"; }));
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Сервер просто рассылает всем сообщение, думал как передать на сервер ip для одиночной рассылки но не знаю как реализовать.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, вы хотите напрямую юзер-юзер открывать канал или через сервер?

Comment: Да, вообщем-то без разницы, если через сервер я не понимаю как передать на сервер ip для последующей перессылки только одному юзеру. А так способ чем проще и короче тем лучше.

Comment: Я бы инкапсулировал все IP на сервере и никому их не давал. Отдавал бы только имена и id юзеров и если надо послать данные швырял бы на сервер этот id и мессадж, а сервер уже выбирал IP и отправлял ему данные. К слову, через SignalR это сделать до невозможности просто.